# Good resources about reversible-jump MCMC sampler in R

Tags: r, references, sas, markov-chain-montecarlo

Please help me to find out simple (I mean useful with little knowledge on Bayesian statistics) resources:

1. To learn MCMC and perform general linear or mixed models
2. To learn different sampling techniques including reverse jump sampler. Also, I want implement these methods using R base or R packages. I can
   use SAS and any other specially designed software, however I have R as
   preference.
3. Example codes to perform MCMC and reversible jump sampler.

Comment: Do you mean [reversible jump MCMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible-jump_Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo)? In my opinion it is impossible to find an R package that does reversible jump in a generic situation, simply because the jumps are very specific. For learning Gibbs on generalised linear models, you can use the [R code available on the webpage](http://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~xian/BCS/) of our book [Bayesian Core](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1441919392?ie=UTF8&tag=chrprobboo-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=1441919392).